# What is the reason for the lack of inheritance of text-decoration?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, properties, text-decorations

So I've read [the previous disccussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491007/why-does-text-decoration-stop-inheriting-based-on-the-positioning-of-the-child-e) on this topic and I understand that text-decoration is propagated instead of inherited, but the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props) doesn't say *why*.  I'm trying to get a better understanding of why this is, and why the positioning matters.  What are the benefits of this behavior?  I was surprised by it because it's non-intuitive.  Are there any other examples of this in CSS that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this mark-up, which pre-dates CSS.

```
<strike>The <a href="http://example.com/">example</a> is here.</strike>
```

`<strike>` is by default `text-decoration:line-through` while `<a href="...">` is by default `text-decoration:underline`. Pre-CSS, the word "example" would be both underlined and struck out, so CSS needed to be able to implement the same effect. To do this, the spec writers chose to make `text-decoration` accumulate rather than inherit.

The alternative would have been to give each `text-decoration` value its own property. The father of CSS, Håkon Wium Lie, addresses this in a [message to the www-style mailing list in May 1997](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1997May/0088.html):

> There is no easy way to turn off blinking without also
> throwing out other values set on the text-decoration property. **This
> was sacrificed for the sake of brevity** -- the alternatives would be to
> have separate binary properties for all values on 'text-decoration'.

At the time it was envisaged that `text-decoration` would be extended to have more than the four decorations it eventually had - [several had already been dropped from the draft spec](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1995Nov/0020.html).

So there you have it, the designers of CSS did not want a proliferation of properties at that time.

---

It's difficult to prove such a negative, but I'm not aware of any other properties that propagate in this way.